# How can I animate height of div in CSS / React js on expand and collapse?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How could I animate the container div's height when collapse and expand? Since when I collapse the card, the footer jumps directly up without easing or animation. (ps. I mean animating the background div height, not the card's height)

[image]

[image]

HTML:

```
<section>
  <Row data-aos="fade-up" className={styles.currRow} xl='2' xs={'1'}>
    {props.res.result_2.map((val, key) => {
    return
    <Col className={styles.CurrCol}>
    <CardBox back={`${generateImage()}`} isOpen={isOpen} setIsOpen={setIsOpen} index={0} title={val.sub_name} par1={val.sub_text} />
    </Col>
    })}
  </Row>
</section>
```

Comment: Doesn't it mean if you apply transition to the card's height, the parent div's height will have a smooth transition? So I don't see why you wouldn't apply transition to the card instead of the background div.

Comment: I applied transition to the card using motion framer it worked but only for the card; the container div doesn't transform smoothly

Comment: @FirasSCMP try adding a min-height to the container and height of auto.